# how to get select value derived from php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two files, one index.php and the other get_content.php, unfortunately I can not show anything on get_content.php, I am confused about where my fault lies either in index.php or get_content.php?

Full Code 
Click [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12329807/)

***index.php***

**AJAX :**

```
     $("#id_content").click(function() {
        var id_content = $("#id_content").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"get_content.php",
            data: "id_content="+id_content,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
                $("#result_of_ajax").html(msg);
            }
        })
    })
```

**PHP :**

```
<select id='id_content' name='id_content'>
                <option value='ID Content'>Content</option>
                <?php
                    $sql = "select id_content from content where status = 'setuju'";
                    $hasil = mysqli_query($konek, $sql);

                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil)) {
                        echo "<option value='$data[id_content]'>$data[content]</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

and here is get_content.php

***get_content.php***

```
echo $_POST['id_content'];
```

why in get_content.php does not show anything ???

Comment: does your **PHP** code output the `<select ...>` options correctly?

Comment: See my comment on my answer Mr Haikal. You will get to know why u will not use $data[id_content] instead of $data['id_content'] . And no need to learn from me. I just know the correct syntax. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not an answer yet. But I believe you should change your jQuery+AJAX code a bit like:

```
$("#id_content").on('change', function() {
    var id_content = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_content.php",
        data: { id_content: id_content },
        cache:false,
        success:function(msg){
            $("#result_of_ajax").html(msg);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have done mistake here `echo "<option value='$data[id_content]'>$data[content]</option>";`
Change to 
<option value=<?echo $data['id_content'];?>><?echo $data['content'];?></option>

And one more change was there.. check below..

<select id='id_content' name='id_content'>
    <option value='ID Content'>Content</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "select id_content from content where status = 'setuju'";
        $hasil = mysqli_query($konek, $sql);

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil)) 
        {?>
            <option value=<?echo $data['id_content'];?>><?echo $data['content'];?></option>
            <?}
    ?>
</select>
<br>
<div id="result_of_ajax">
</div>

$("#id_content").on('change', function() {
    var id_content = $('#id_content').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"get_content.php?id_content="+id_content,
        cache:false,
        success:function(msg){
            $("#result_of_ajax").html(msg);
        }
    })
})
```

**get_content.php**

```
<?echo $_GET['id_content'];?>
```

Comment: wow danish you are smart man, i need to learn more ajax, can you explain to me why i can not use this ->  echo "<option value='$data[id_content]'>$data[content]</option>"; ???

Comment: $data['Id_content'] is the correct syntax Mr @Haikal.

Comment: $data['Id_content'] is correct syntax.  $data[Id_content]  is not correct syntax Mr @Haikal